# How to solve this trig. equation?

Tags: trigonometry

I've been struggling with this equation for hours. I've tried manipulating it, but had no luck. Any help appreciated!

$2\sin x \cos x-3\sin x-3\cos x+3=0$

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? $x=0$ is a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$2\sin{x} \cos{x}-3\sin{x}-3\cos{x}+3=(\sin{x}+\cos{x})^2-3(\sin{x}+\cos{x})+2$$

Comment: nice observation there .

Comment: Thanks, didn't noticed that.